# laravel 5.1 : how can i get nested relation from model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, relationship

I have a question about laravel model relations and use them in eloquent class . my question is this :

I have a model like this :

```
class TransferFormsContent extends Model
{

 public function transferForm()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TransfersForms','form_id');
    }
}
```

and in transferForm i have other side for this relation like this :

```
  public function transferFormsContent()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TransferFormsContent', 'form_id', 'id');
}
```

also in transferForm i have another relation with employee like this :

```
class TransfersForms extends Model
{
     public function employee()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User','employee_id');
        }
}
```

now if I want get a record from "TransferFormsContent" with its "transferForm " provided its with employee. how can i do this?

i now if i want get "TransferFormsContent" with only "transferForm " i can use from this :

```
 $row = $this->model
            ->with('transferForm');
```

but how about if i want transferForm also be with its employee?

Comment: Does [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i find that:

only you can do that with this :

```
 $row = $this->model
            ->with('transferForm.employee')
```

now you have a record from "TransferFormsContent" with its "transferForm " provided its with employee.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested eager loading with dot notation:

```
$row = $this->model
        ->with('transferForm.employee');
```

Or you can use closure:

```
$row->$this->model
        ->with(['transferForm' => function($q) {
              $q->with('employee')
}]);
```

Second method is useful when you need to sort or filter by employee